# Rails, Rspec: "expect" method inside "before" block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm collaborating on a Rails application where the test suite is full of this kind of declarations:

```
before do
  expect(job_post).to receive(:destroy).and_return(true)
  delete :destroy, params_id
end
```

(And the test suite is green)

Now, using `expect` inside a `before` block doesn't make sense to me. I can't find any documentation on the subject.

What's even weirder, is that it seems to act as a sort of stub. If I remove it, the tests fail.

### UPDATE:

Someone has already replied with a refactored test.
While appreciated (thanks), that does not answer my question. In fact, I know how to write controller specs and eventually I will completely rewrite this test file.

My question is about:

1. Does the code I reported make sense?
2. Is this use of `expect` documented? Where?
3. If it does make sense, could someone provide some pointers?

Comment: Please include a complete example of Rspec, with the corresponding `it`.

Comment: That's the point. There is NO `it`. When there is an `it` block, it tests something completely unrelated (e.g. the `flash`)

Comment: Try replacing it with `job_post.stub(:destroy).and_return(true)`

Comment: I think you can move the content of your `before` block to an `it` and it should works as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I would really like to know if the quoted block of code makes sense. I don't think it does, but I'd like to know what others think.

Comment: Well, this is a controller test?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is. It's a controller test filled with "implementation probes"... which I'm trying to remove, because they are making refactoring impossible.

Comment: It seems that this is expecting each of your tests do call `destroy` method on job_object. Could you also post at least one test which is failing when you remove this line?

Comment: it makes sense, but I don't consider it very good form.  Using `expect` in a `before` block can cause a batch of tests to fail for an unrelated reason.  They're doing it here for two reasons.

1. It stubs the method
2. it tests that the method got called.

and, in fact, the previous programmer probably only intended (1) and may not have been aware that `allow` exists.

Equivalent with better form might be be to use `allow(job_post).to receive(:destroy).and_return(true)`, and then perhaps ALSO have some tests with the expectation in an `it` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup it doesn't make sense. If they wanted to simulate the job_post receive thing they should have done it using a stub, not actually doing an operation on the object. Then they do a `delete` for what reason, exactly?

It's not free but for pointers I'd go to [Destroy All Software](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/growing-a-test-suite). There's just a lot of cool things about tests there. I also recently watched [The Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M), it's helped me a lot on the whole testing thing in general.